# Can subclass inherit interface implementation from parent unrelated to the interface

Tags: java, polymorphism

This is kind of quirk or corner case. Consider this example:

```
interface I {
    void foo();
}

class B {
    public void foo() {}
}

class C extends B implements I {}
```

With my compiler (OpenJDK in Linux) it compiles and the following works:

```
I c = new C();
c.foo();
```

Why? Is it intentional and backed by the language standard? How the runtime knows to follow first "down" from `I` to `C` and then "up" from `C` to `B`? While that would be clear in case `B implements I`, it seems counter intuitive given `B` unrelated to `I`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in the example you mentioned `c` is an `instanceof` the `class C`. Hence, it would require to have it's own method `foo()`.

Now, C has gotten all public (and default?) methods from `B` and `foo()` happens to be one that is (technically) present, thanks to `B`. Hence, the requirement that the interface placed on `C`, to have its own `foo()` method, is fulfilled by `B`s `foo()`.

I don't think the down from I to C, and up from C to B is relevant here, in the way you mentioned it.

EDIT:

All evidence points to the fact that the compiler has at-hand, a list of *implemented* functions, both that **are in** the given class, and **'virtual'** ones that are extended from the parent class.

As a result, if the aforementioned class is implementing some interface, both extended and the classes own functions are tallied against the ones that needed to be implemented (because of the interface).

Comment: Is it correct to assume, compiler first gets a list of all the **implemented** functions, both directly and through superclasses, and only after that verifies the interface?

Comment: @IliaBarahovski Yes! All evidence points directly to that. You are absolutely correct.

Comment: @IliaBarahovski Is it better now?

Answer (score 1):

When you written `class C extends B implements I` following will happen From [JLS 8.4.8 Inheritance, Overriding, and Hiding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8):

> **A class C inherits from its direct superclass all concrete methods m (both static and instance) of the superclass for which all of the following are true:**
>
> - m is a member of the direct superclass of C.
> - m is public, protected, or declared with package access in the same package as C.
> - No method declared in C has a signature that is a subsignature (§8.4.2) of the signature of m.
>
> **A class C inherits from its direct superclass and direct superinterfaces all abstract and default (§9.4) methods m for which all of the following are true:**
>
> - m is a member of the direct superclass or a direct superinterface, D, of C.
> - m is public, protected, or declared with package access in the same package as C.
> - No method declared in C has a signature that is a subsignature (§8.4.2) of the signature of m.
> - No concrete method inherited by C from its direct superclass has a signature that is a subsignature of the signature of m.
> - There exists no method m' that is a member of the direct superclass or a direct superinterface, D', of C (m distinct from m', D distinct from D'), such that m' from D' overrides the declaration of the method m.

So its inherits abstract method from  `interface I` and a concrete methods with same signature from `class B`.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really "follow" like you think. `C` inherits all non-private methods from `B`, and `C` can do whatever it wants with those methods; override them, use them to implement interfaces (if the method is `public`), invoke them, etc.

So the method `foo` is a method of `C`, even if it came by the method by inheriting it from `B`. And a class can expose any of its public methods through an `interface`.

Answer (score -1):

The first thing to note is the common effect of `extending B and implementing I`. The common effect or the obvious outcome in java is that you can have only one `method with a particular name, datatype and parameters(same type and equal in number)`.

Any method which has the same name and different number of arguments would be a case of method overloading. But in your case, it's pretty simple that you need to implement and define the abstarct method `foo()` in `I` in a concrete subclass which in this case is `C`.

It's not compulsory to redefine every method in the superclass but it becomes compulsory when you are implementing an interface. So Java considers this `method foo()` in the `class C` as the inherited method from the `interface I`. Otherwise you would have seen an error asking you to redefine the `method foo()` which is inherited from the interface.

Unknowingly this also becomes a case of method overriding when you consider the superclass `B`. Since the `foo()` method in `C` has the same kind of declaration as in `B` and `I` (which it should according to the standards, rules and to satisfy the rules of implementing an interface), it easily satisfies the interface as well as overrides the method in `B`.

In your case, you are also overriding the method `foo()` in class `B`.

So one condition as well as a complementary offer (overriding) is being satisfied.

In the end, `class C` has just one `foo()` method which overrides the method in `B` as well as satisfies the condition of `implementing interface I`.

An example:

Let the method `foo()` be defined (in `C`) as:

```
void foo()
{
System.out.println("Hello");
}
```

Create 2 objects in `C` as follows:

```
B b=new C();
C c=new C();
```

Call `foo()`:

```
b.foo();
c.foo();
```

Ouput: Both prints `Hello`.

Conclusion: `foo()` in `C` satisfies the interface (no error seen) and also overrides the method `foo()` in `B`.

Comment: you meant interface `I`

Comment: @DebosmitRay Thanks..Corrected it.